# Store a api response data in firebase collections using flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So, I have been making a post request to a REST API and I want to store the response data in the firebase cloud store collection.
**What I have done so far:**
I have created the model class for the response data and have written a function that will make this post-call.

I am not getting any such error but still, neither the response is getting printed in the console nor the data is being uploaded in the firebase.
Also, I have checked with almost all the StackOverflow questions that relate to my kind of problem.

Herewith I am attaching my code snippets:

**Function:**
*//This function is only not getting called I don't know why.*

```
final List<KycDetails> _kyc = [];
  Dio dio = Dio();
  TextEditingController aadhar = TextEditingController();
  Future<List<KycDetails>> postData() async {
    const String pathUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    dynamic data = {'title': aadhar.text, 'body': 'Flutter', 'userId': 1};
    List<KycDetails> details = [];
    var response = await dio.post(pathUrl,
        data: data,
        options: Options(
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('ok');
      var urjson = jsonDecode(response.data);
      for (var jsondata in urjson) {
        details.add(KycDetails.fromJson(jsondata));
      }
    }
    return details;
  }
```

**Widget where I am calling the function and storing the data in firebase**

```
     InkWell( 
                  hoverColor: Colors.red,
                  onTap: () async {
                    print('API CALLING');
                    await postData().then((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _kyc.addAll(value);
                      });
                      print(value);
                      
                    });
                    Map<String, String> data = {
                      "aadhar": aadhar.text,
                      "title": _kyc[0].title,
                      "userId": _kyc[0].userId.toString(),
                    };
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kyc').add(data);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
```

**API response data:**

```
{"title": "resume", "body": "Flutter", "userId": 1, "id": 101}
```

**Model Class:**

```
class KycDetails {
  KycDetails({
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
  });

  String title;
  String body;
  int userId;
  int id;

  factory KycDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => KycDetails(
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
        userId: json["userId"],
        id: json["id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "userId": userId,
        "id": id,
      };
}
```

I hope I have provided you with the necessary information
Am stuck on this problem for quite a few days Would appreciate it if anyone can solve my problem considering my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, when you make a post request the success code you're looking for is `201` indicating that a resource has been successfully created.

So nothing in this code block will run.

```
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('ok');
      var urjson = jsonDecode(response.data);
      for (var jsondata in urjson) {
        details.add(KycDetails.fromJson(jsondata));
      }
    }
```

`response.data` doesn't need `jsonDecode` here. It returns in the form of a `map` so you can cast it as such.

So this

```
var urjson = jsonDecode(response.data);
```

can be this

```
final urjson = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

As for this line

```
   for (var jsondata in urjson) {
        details.add(KycDetails.fromJson(jsondata));
      }
```

The response is a single `map`, not a list. That single `map` is in the form of your `KycDetails` model so you don't need to loop through anything.

So you can create your object with your `fromJson` method.

```
final kycDetail = KycDetails.fromJson(urjson);
```

Then you can just do this to add a properly initiated `KycDetails` object to the list.

```
details.add(kycDetail);
```

If all you're trying to do is add a single object to Firebase then none of this in your `onTap` is necessary. Also trying to access the property at index 0 will not be the most recent addition to the list. You'd need to add the index of the last item in the list.

```
Map<String, String> data = {
  "aadhar": aadhar.text,
  "title": _kyc[0].title,
  "userId": _kyc[0].userId.toString(),
};

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kyc').add(data);
```

You can just add to Firebase from your `postData` function.

```
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('ok');
    final urjson = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final kycDetail = KycDetails.fromJson(urjson);
    details.add(kycDetail);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kyc').add(kycDetail.toJson());
  }
```